# Como posso fazer um script de ano novo?

Tags: javascript, data

Bom galera, procurei como fazer mas não consegui. Quero um código em javascript que ative automaticamente somente após a meia noite. Veja o código:

```
var agora = new Date();
var anoNovo = new Date(2017, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var anoNovoMax = new Date(2017, 0, 1, 23, 59, 59, 0);
if(agora >= anoNovo && agora<anoNovoMax)
{
$('#musica').html('<audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" style="display:none"> <source src="../fogos.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /></audio>');
$('#foguetes').html('<div class="fogos"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use o `new Date()` com o `.getFullYear()`, que retorna o ano. Caso seja 2017, executa seu código:

```js
var interval;

function happyNewYear() {
  var date = new Date();

  if (date.getFullYear() == 2017) {
    console.log('Ano novo!!');
    
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

interval = setInterval(happyNewYear, 1000); // Executa a função a cada 1 segundo
```

No caso, você precisa de um loop (`setInterval`) para que verifique a cada segundo se já é ano novo.

Guarde o intervalo em uma variável.

Quando for ano novo, o `clearInterval()` ficará responsável de finalizar o loop o que executará a função apenas uma vez.

Vale lembrar que como não há conexão com o servidor, esse horário será igual ao do computador do usuário.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo!

Comment: marque a resposta, @hanz